# how to use infer to infer the return type of a void function?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to better understand using `infer` keyword in typescript.

Would this be a valid demonstration on using infer properly ?

I want to just infer the return type of the following function,

```
const [name, setName] = useState<string>('');
const [age, setAge] = useState<number>();

type CallbackType<T> = T extends () => infer R ? R: never

function stateCallback<T>(name: string, age: number): CallbackType<T>{
  setName(name)
  setAge(age);
}
```

It should return a void type as im not returning anything, is this the right approach on using `infer` ?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBA2mAhgWwKYBoYVVAci1AXRgF4YBXbAZSkSlQB5oAnASzAHMA+ACgHI+ASgDcAWABQoSLDiIOGLDgCC84mUqoadRmHLIARqma8REiVACeAB1QwAwogA2j-YmABrACrXGnrqRhPGFQAD3owABMIGB5BUn92ADMjGAAlGAB+NIAuGDBUADcjM3FE8jBgKFZwLFp6B2dXDwY-HiQ0XJZ2Dkw5VFzdAyNBXIaXNy8fFq4AbwkYRTwCNoJBecWVVB4+03EAXyA)

Comment: you defined `CallbackType<T>` correctly (although there is already a `ReturnType<T>` provided), using it that way doesn't work because you can't have a function that has a generic return type `T` (that's inferred for the function) but doesn't actually return anything. If you want to specify the return type for that function if has to be (or include) `void` which needs no inferring.

Comment: I see what you're saying, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: correction: it obviously won't inferred as `T`, because it's either `R` (which has no bounds, so essentially `any`) or `never`. But that still means it's not `void`. (I guess `any | never` would mean the same as `any`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not how `infer` should be used. If you want TypeScript to *infer* the return type of the function, just don't specify a return type.

```
function stateCallback(name: string, age: number) {
  setName(name)
  setAge(age);
}
// return type of stateCallback is inferred as void
```

The `infer` keyword can be used (among other things) to *extract* information from a type. So if you pass a function type to `CallbackType`, it will return the function's return type.

```
type CallbackType<T> = T extends () => infer R ? R : never

type Result = CallbackType<() => string>
// -> string
```

Comment: upvoted.. that makes sense... But suppose i want to create a reusable function that takes in a callback, how could i express the return type of that callback thats passed in as an argument ?

`reusableFunction(callbackFn) => {}`

Comment: @BARNOWL - I am not quite sure what you mean. Could share a Playground with the desired behavior? You can always specify the callback type like this: `function fn(callback: () => string)`.

Comment: that example you showed above is suffice enough for an example. What if i don't want to supply a string as return type. How could the return type be inferred using `infer`.

Would a generic `<T>` be a more appropriate approach ?

Comment: @BARNOWL - Do you mean something like this?: `function fn<T>(callback: () => T)`

Comment: Yes, would that be more ideal opposed to using infer ?

Comment: @BARNOWL - You can't really use `infer` to achieve this behavior :/ so I am not sure  what you are getting at. `infer` can only be used inside conditional types.

Comment: Its all good you answered my question will accept, thanks Tobias.